# Publish options in Visual Studio - web vs filessytem

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

Have a .net core web app that I am publishing to a test server.  What is the difference on the IIS instance between a file publish vs a web publish.

Does using the file publish options cause the app pool to release its hold on any files?

On a regular basis, if I publish files to a test server, it will succeed but then after i have hit a few pages on the site and publish another update, it will fail with errors of "access denied".  However, If I simply follow up with another publish, it will work.  The errors indicate it has issues deleting the files from the target folder, which is an option I have set in the publish profile.

Answer (score 0):

File publish is, as it's name indicates, for publishing to the filesystem. Typically, this is going to be your local filesystem, but I suppose a network location works just as well.

Web publish is specifically for deploying to IIS. It uses Web Deploy to coordinate with the destination IIS instance to do things like start and stop the site, or even create the site in the first place, if it doesn't already exist, and of course pushes the published files to the web root for that site.

If you're doing something like doing a file publish directly to the web root of an IIS using a UNC connection or something, then that could definitely cause problems. The idea of a file publish is that you're going to manually take those files somewhere yourself. Otherwise, if your goal is to actually publish to IIS anyways, then use the web publish.

Answer (score 0):

file-system Web site lets you a folder on your local hard disk or in a shared location on your local area network.

You could use a file system in below situation:

- when you do not want to install iis.
- when you have already web site files and open that as a project.

  Visual Studio will create the folder, if necessary, and populate it with the files from the Web site project template that you have selected. For example, if you create a Web site project by using the ASP.NET Web Site template, Visual Studio creates a default pages such as Default.aspx and default folders such as App_Data in the location that you specify.

web deploy is used If you have IIS on server machine running and configured to receive Web Deploy requests, it will send all requested by IIS files. IIS will immediately start running new web page.

Regards,
Jalpa.